# How to import child component in the parent component which is in an HTML file (react.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My EJS file (which is rendered as HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
  <body>
    <div id="choose-your-box"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      const merged_boxes = <%-JSON.stringify(merged_boxes)%>;
    </script>

    <script type="text/babel" src="/react/boxes.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

boxes.js

```
class Boxes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Box/>; <--- HERE, how do I properly import the box.js file?
  }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector("#choose-your-box");
ReactDOM.render(<Boxes />, domContainer);
```

box.js

```
class Box extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

export default Box;
```

So how do I import box.js inside boxes.js? Obviously I omitted lots of codes to make it look cleaner, so let me know if anyone has any question.

Comment: Assuming `boxes.js` is located at the same level with `box.js`, why don't you just place `import Box from './box';` at the top of `boxes.js`?

Comment: Are you not using any build tool like Webpack ?

Comment: @filipvkovic ah no, I can't do that since "import" wouldn't be defined in the browser...

Comment: @VishalSharma no

Comment: @filipvkovic `boxes.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` when I use `import Box from "./box"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `Box.js` script tag above `Boxes.js` like this:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="/PATH_TO_BOXJS/box.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="/react/boxes.js"></script>
```

and then Use it `without` importing like this:

```
class Boxes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Box/>; {/*<--- It should be fine this time*/}
  }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector("#choose-your-box");
ReactDOM.render(<Boxes />, domContainer);
```

You can also remove `export phrase` from `box.js` because you won't need it.

`box.js`:

```
class Box extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is throwing another error now: `exports is not defined`

Comment: Also this: `react_devtools_backend.js:6 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Comment: like I showed you above , you don't need the `export phrase` anymore because you don't use any `build setup`

Comment: I forgot to remove `export default Box` from box.js!

Answer (score 0):

You first have to import `Box` component in Boxes file.

Comment: I can't do that since it's not a regular react project that is using webpack and stuff, I'm importing react through <script>, not npm if you noticed